# htaccess: how to redirect all folder pages to same folder name on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all pages of a certain section of my main domain (called "articoli") to a subdomain section which has the same name (articoli) in the .htaccess file of my main domain (mydomain.com) I put this redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(old)\.domain\.net [NC]

RewriteRule ^articoli(.*)$ http://old.domain.net/articoli/$1[r=301,L]
```

**but this causes issues:**
`mydomain.net/articoli` is being redirected to `old.mydomain/articoli`

but my `domain.net/articoli/something.php` is NOT being redirected to `old.domain.net/articoli/something.php`, it just send me back to `domain.net/articoli/something.php`

There must be something wrong in the rule I added, but I am no expert on this so I can't find what, I just copied that rule from another stackideas answer.

How can I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the htaccess for the old.mydomain.com/articoli?

Comment: old.mydomain.com has its own .htaccess and it's a default joomla .htaccess, it has no custom rules at all, just the default rules to make the joomla sef url feature work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
RewriteRule ^articoli(.*)$ http://old.domain.net/articoli/$1[r=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^articoli/(.*)$ http://old.domain.net/articoli/$1 [R=302,L]
```

should work (change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure everything works).

Comment: now I inserted 


`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(old)\.alkemica\.net [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^articoli1/(.*)$ http://old.alkemica.net/articoli/$1[R=302,L]`


yes "articoli1" is the correct path on the main domain


right now nothing is being redirected by visiting this page http://www.alkemica.net/articoli1 or any of the blog articles


I try to attach the full htaccess file

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but now I have another issue - this rule redirects all the pages inside the folder correctly, but not the main folder... http://domain.com/articoli1 is not being redirected to http://old.domain.com/articoli

Comment: could you edit your first post with the contents of the htaccess file?